# Selecionar um badge como elemento filho Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um badge que é atributo filho de um button, dessa forma:

```
   <button id="equipeum" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><span id ="pontoum"class="badge"></span></button>
```

Nesse caso o badge seria um elemento filho do button (me corrijam se estiver errado), enfim, meu problema é conseguir alterar os valores dos dois, pois quando o eu altero o valor do `button` "equipeum" via JS, o elemento filho `badge` se perde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago, se você quiser inserir algum conteúdo dentro do elemento `button` e do elemento `span`, você pode fazer assim:

```
$('button').prepend('Nome');
$('span').text(1);
```

Comment: Na verdade eu quero usar os 2 elementos, o Button recebe um valor e o Span que é filho dele, recebe outro. Saca?

Comment: @TiagoSilveira, por valor você quer dizer o conteúdo do elemento?

Comment: Isso @leoklaj, o botão recebe um nome e o badge recebe uma numeração, só que quando eu pego o botão pelo id, ele acaba preenchendo tudo e eu não consigo alterar o conteúdo do badge.

Comment: $('button').prepend('nome aqui') e $('span').text(1)

Comment: Perfeito @leoklaj, edita a resposta pra eu poder dar como certa.